# AggregateException in release mode

Tags: c#, task, aggregateexception

I have three tasks and I called 
Task.WaitAll(task1,task2,task3) after I started the three tasks.

This program works fine in debug mode.
When it turns to release mode, an AggregateException throwed.

I would like to know how can I find the cause of the exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception and then print out each of the inner exceptions like so:

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    foreach (Exception exx in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine(exx.Message);
}
```

Comment: i forgot to put a file under release folder.